# Angular directive is not working when used with two HTML elements?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I have created one directive using AngularJS which is working fine for me, but when i used this same directive with another HTML element then its not working.

```
basecampModule.directive("slideElement", function () {
  function link($scope, element, attributes) {
    var expression = attributes.slideElement;

    if (!$scope.$eval(expression)) {
      element.hide();
    }

    $scope.$watch(expression, function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue === oldValue) {
        return;
      }

      if (newValue) {
        element.stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        element.stop(true, true).slideUp("fast");
      }
    });
  }

  return ({
    link: link,
    restrict: "A"
  });
});
```

HTML Part

```
<div class="row well" id="detailsBugs" slide-element="FilterBugsDetails.ShowPanel">
       //FIRST ELEMENT
</div>

<div class="row well" id="detailsTasks" slide-element="FilterTaskDetails.ShowPanel">
       //SECOND ELEMENT
</div>
```

its working with first element but not with second element.

Please let me know what is wrong is that part. ??

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: And explain what exactly does not work.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem but it looks strange to me that you share the scope with two elements that seem to be separated. I'd add `scope: true` in your directive definition object

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ravimittal/5kx8F/2/

Comment: Your fiddle has bugs.

Comment: that is what i want to know. Can you update JSFiddle and send me a new link of that. It will be a pleasure

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong with my script.

Answer (score 1):

A very wilde guess : you should isolate the scope of you directive. Since both instances of this directive are using the same $scope they're probably conflicting :

http://www.egghead.io/video/fYgdU7u2--g

Answer (score 0):

When I first looked at this I couldn't quite work out what was going on.
The watched would fire for once but not a second time for the second directive.

However, turns out the directive is actually watching two different properties (maybe this was obvious to others but I completely missed it). From the question it sounded like the poster wanted the directive to watch the same element.

Anyway it works fine in [my plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EdyBih?p=preview)

```
<button ng-click="FilterBugsDetails.ShowPanel = !FilterBugsDetails.ShowPanel;">Toggle Bugs</button>
<button ng-click="FilterTaskDetails.ShowPanel = !FilterTaskDetails.ShowPanel;">Toggle Tasks</button>
<button ng-click="FilterTaskDetails.ShowPanel = !FilterTaskDetails.ShowPanel; FilterBugsDetails.ShowPanel = !FilterBugsDetails.ShowPanel;">Toggle Tasks And Bugs</button>
```

Comment: I didn't change the directive at all. The problem you have is that you are not changing the property that the second element is watching. If you change that it will work fine. Your fiddle is not working for a different reason, you haven't included jquery and are using jquerys hide method.